# using Flutter google mobile ads and implementing Banner ad is randomly Loading in Log ,

Tags: flutter, ads

```
here is my code
[enter image description here][1]
        import 'dart:async';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
        import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
        
        import 'adstate.dart';
        
        
        class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
        }
        
        class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
          BannerAd bannerAd;
          void didChangeDependencies(){
            super.didChangeDependencies();
        
            final adState=Provider.of<AdState>(context);
            adState.initialization.then((status){
              setState(() {
                bannerAd= BannerAd(
                  adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
                  size: AdSize.banner,
                  request: AdRequest(),
                  listener:adState.adListener
                )..load();
        
              });
            });
          }
          @override
          void dispose(){
            bannerAd.dispose();
            super.dispose();
        
          }
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
        
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("banner ads checking"),
                  if(bannerAd==null)
                    SizedBox(height: 50,)
                  else
                   Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child:AdWidget(
                      ad: bannerAd,
                      ))
        
        
                  ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    
    ///
    my ad state class

    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';



    class AdState{
      Future<InitializationStatus> initialization;
      AdState(this.initialization);
      String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid
          ?'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
          :'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
    
    AdListener get adListener=> _adListener;
    
      AdListener _adListener=AdListener(
      onAdLoaded: (ad) =>print("Ad Loaded:${ad.adUnitId}."),
      onAdFailedToLoad: (ad,error) {
        print("Ad failed to load:${ad.adUnitId}.$error");
      },
      onAdOpened: (ad) => print("Ad Loaded:${ad.adUnitId}."),
      onAdClosed: (ad) => print("Ad closed:${ad.adUnitId}."),
          onAppEvent: (ad,name,data)=>
              print("Ad event:${ad.adUnitId}.$name,$data"),
      onApplicationExit: (ad) =>print("App Exit:${ad.adUnitId}."),
        onNativeAdClicked: (nativeAd)=>
            print("Native add clicked:${nativeAd.adUnitId}."),
       onNativeAdImpression:  (nativeAd)=>
           print("Native add Impression:${nativeAd.adUnitId}."),
      onRewardedAdUserEarnedReward: (ad,reward)=>
          print("Native add Impression:${ad.adUnitId}.${reward.type}"),
    
      );
    
    }
    

////main Class
    
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
        import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
        import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
        import 'package:voiceassistance/homePage.dart';
        
        import 'adstate.dart';
        
        void main() {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
          final initFuture=MobileAds.instance.initialize();
          final adsatate=AdState(initFuture);
          SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
          runApp(
            Provider.value(value: adsatate,
            builder: (context, child)=>
            MyApp(),
            ));
        }
        class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home:BannerAdWidget(),
            );
          }
        }

this my log picturre


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhs39.png
```

above code loads a banner ad but how  can I dispose it , in background it generates de web view logs which compromise the app performance,
please help I am stuck,
above code is saperated by comments (main class, ad mobe class, widget class)
above code loads a banner ad but how  can I dispose it , in background it generates de web view logs which compromise the app performance,
please help I am stuck,
above code is saperated by comments (main class, ad mobe class, widget class)
above code loads a banner ad but how  can I dispose it , in background it generates de web view logs which compromise the app performance,
please help I am stuck,
above code is saperated by comments (main class, ad mobe class, widget class)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxqWO.png)